# How to connect Alpine Linux to WiFi?

Tags: wifi, alpine-linux

I can't finish setup at all - Alpine seems to expect you to be connected to Ethernet for installing `wireless-tools` and `wpa_supplicant`.

Is this correct?
My issue is: I don't have a monitor where my router is, so it's a chicken and egg problem: can't connect to the internet because `wireless-tools` don't come with Alpine's default install, and can't install them because I'm not connected to the Internet.

Answer (score 4):

If you are using the alpine extended iso, some packages are on it - you can install them without internet connection just

```
apk add wireless-tools wpa_supplicant
```

and it will install. Then follow the [wiki page](http://wiki.alpinelinux.org/wiki/Main_Page).

Comment: I'm simply following http://wiki.alpinelinux.org/wiki/Raspberry_Pi
What is alpine extended iso?

Comment: Alpine Extended version:
https://alpinelinux.org/downloads

Comment: I installed extended alpine Linux with the iso over usb, rebooted and apk add wireless-tools shows: error unsatisfiable constraints: wireless-tools(missing): required by world[wireless-tools]

Comment: `apk add` requires internet. Without wifi, many devices don’t have one.